# How to transform multiple features in a PipeLine using FeatureUnion?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science, multilabel-classification

I have a pandas data frame that contains information about messages sent by user.
For my model, I'm interested in predicting missing recipients of a message i,e given recipients A,B,C of a message I want to predict who else should have been part of the recipients.

I'm doing multi-label classification using OneVsRestClassifier and LinearSVC.
For features, I want to use the recipients of the message. subject and body.

Since recipients is a list of users, I want to transform that column using MultiLabelBinarizer. For Subject and Body, I want to use TFIDF

My input pickle file has data as follows: All values are strings except recipients which is a set()

```
[[message_id,sent_time,subject,body,set(recipients),message_type, is_sender]]
```

I'm using feature union with custom transformers in the pipeline to achieve this as follows.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, column):
        self.column = column

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return X[self.column]

class MultiLabelTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, column):
        self.column = column

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
        return mlb.fit_transform(X[self.column])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('subject_tfidf', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='Subject')),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0025, ngram_range=(1, 4)))
                    ])),
        ('body_tfidf', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='Body')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0025, ngram_range=(1, 4)))
        ])),
        ('recipients_binarizer', Pipeline([
            ('multi_label', MultiLabelTransformer(column='CoRecipients'))
        ])),
    ])),
    ('classifier', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=-1))
])

top_recips = ['A', 'B', 'C, 'D]
corpus_data = pickle.load(
    open("E:\\Data\\messages_items.pkl", "rb"))
df = pd.DataFrame(corpus_data, columns=[
    'MessageId', 'SentTime', 'Subject', 'Body', 'Recipients', 'MessageType', 'IsSender'])

df = df.dropna()

# add co recipients and top recipients columns
df['CoRecipients'] = df['Recipients'].apply(
    lambda r: [x for x in r if x not in top_recips])
df['TopRecipients'] = df['Recipients'].apply(
    lambda r: [x for x in top_recips if x in r])

# drop rows where top recipients = 0
df = df.loc[df['TopRecipients'].str.len() > 0]
df_train = df.loc[df['SentTime'] <= '2017-10-15']
df_test = df.loc[(df['SentTime'] > '2017-10-15') & (df['MessageType'] == 'Meeting')]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=top_recips)

train_x = df_train[['Subject', 'Body', 'CoRecipients']]
train_y = mlb.fit_transform(df_train['TopRecipients'])

test_x = df_train[['Subject', 'Body', 'CoRecipients']]
test_y = mlb.fit_transform(df_train['TopRecipients'])

print "train"
pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)

print "predict"
predictions = pipeline.predict(test_x)

print "done"
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the featurization of the CoRecipients column correctly. As the results dont look right. Any clue?

> **UPDATE 1**

Changed the code of MLB transformer as follows:

```
class MultiLabelTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, column):
            self.column = column

        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            self.mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
            self.mlb.fit(X[self.column])
            return self

        def transform(self, X):
            return self.mlb.transform(X[self.column])
```

And fixed the test set to use df_test

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=top_recips)

train_x = df_train[['Subject', 'Body', 'CoRecipients']]
train_y = mlb.fit_transform(df_train['TopRecipients'])

test_x = df_test[['Subject', 'Body', 'CoRecipients']]
test_y = mlb.transform(df_test['TopRecipients'])
```

Seeing the below KeyError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\NLP\FeatureUnion.py", line 99, in <module>
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py", line 115, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 306, in predict
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 768, in transform
    for name, trans, weight in self._iter())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 571, in _transform_one
    res = transformer.transform(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 426, in _transform
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "E:\Projects\NLP\FeatureUnion.py", line 37, in transform
    return self.mlb.transform(X[self.column])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 765, in transform
    yt = self._transform(y, class_to_index)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 789, in _transform
    indices.extend(set(class_mapping[label] for label in labels))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 789, in <genexpr>
    indices.extend(set(class_mapping[label] for label in labels))
KeyError: u'cf3024@gmail.com'
```

**> UPDATE 2**

Working code

```
 class MultiLabelTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, column, classes):
            self.column = column
            self.classes = classes
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=self.classes)
        self.mlb.fit(X[self.column])
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.mlb.transform(X[self.column])

# drop rows where top recipients = 0
df = df.loc[df['TopRecipients'].str.len() > 0]
df_train = df.loc[df['SentTime'] <= '2017-10-15']
df_test = df.loc[(df['SentTime'] > '2017-10-15') &
                 (df['MessageType'] == 'Meeting')]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=top_recips)

train_x = df_train[['Subject', 'Body', 'CoRecipients']]
train_y = mlb.fit_transform(df_train['TopRecipients'])

test_x = df_test[['Subject', 'Body', 'CoRecipients']]
test_y = mlb.transform(df_test['TopRecipients'])

# get all unique co-recipients
co_recips = list(set([a for b in df.CoRecipients.tolist() for a in b]))

# create pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion(
        # list of features
        transformer_list=[
            ('subject_tfidf', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='Subject')),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0025, ngram_range=(1, 4)))
                    ])),
            ('body_tfidf', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='Body')),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0025, ngram_range=(1, 4)))
            ])),
            ('recipients_binarizer', Pipeline([
                ('multi_label', MultiLabelTransformer(column='CoRecipients', classes=co_recips))
            ]))
        ],
        # weight components in FeatureUnion
        transformer_weights={
            'subject_tfidf': 3.0,
            'body_tfidf': 1.0,
            'recipients_binarizer': 1.0,
        }
    )),
    ('classifier', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=-1))
])

print "train"
pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)

print "predict"
predictions = pipeline.predict(test_x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the transforming for MultiLabelBinarizer wrong. You are fitting for both training and testing data. Thats not correct way.

You should only always fit on training data and use transform on test data.

You have done this mistake two times:

- In MultiLabelTransformer, where you transform the 'Co-recipients'
- During transforming the test_y, where you transform the 'TopRecipients'

The problem is when test data have different (or new) values in 'Co-recipients' or 'TopRecipients', the returned array will have different shape than what it had during training time. That will result in wrong results.

Change your code like this:

```
class MultiLabelTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    #Updated
    def __init__(self, column, classes):
        self.column = column
        self.classes = classes

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # Updated
        self.mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes = self.classes)
        self.mlb.fit(X[self.column])
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.mlb.transform(X[self.column])
```

And

```
test_y = mlb.transform(df_train['TopRecipients'])
```

And inside the pipeline:

```
....
....
('multi_label', MultiLabelTransformer(column='CoRecipients',
                                      classes=set([a for b in df.CoRecipients.tolist() for a in b]))
....
....
```

Although the last change in `test_y` will not affect the returned array because you have specified the classes using `top_recips` during `mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=top_recips)`, but its still better to do only transform (and never fit or fit_transform) on the test data.

Comment: I changed the code for MultiLabelTrasnformer as you suggested and I'm now getting a KeyError when trying to predict on test_x

Update the code in the Q with changes suggested. I believe the error is happening because there are some recipients who only show up in the test data who are not present in the train data as you alluded to.

How can I fix this such that the multi label binarizer know about all possible recipients in both train and test sets?

Comment: @user330612 Use the classes attribute in the `MultiLabelTrasnformer` for all the known labels in the CoRecipients column. Just as you have done for the y_train and y_test.

Comment: Got that. But how do I pass in this list of unique CoRecipients to the MultiLabelTransformer?

co_recips = list(set([a for b in df.CoRecipients.tolist() for a in b]))

Comment: @user330612 Yes, only set will also do. No need to convert it to list.

Comment: I know how to get the unique list but can't seem to figure out how to pass it to the MultiLabelTransofmer's fit method?

Comment: @user330612 Dont pass it to fit(). Pass it to the constructor. I have updated the answer

Comment: that worked thanks. Only change is the classes needs to be a list not set else it throws an error "unhashable type set". Updated my answer with the fix

Comment: @user330612 Oh ok. Thanks for updating on this.