# Custom MultiLabelBinarizer drops classes when calling fit/transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Like [several people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254662/sklearn-columntransformer-with-multilabelbinarizer), I've been trying to use a `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer` within a `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer` pipeline, to little avail. Using some hints from answers in the linked thread, I came up with the following class, `ComposableMultiLabelBinarizer`. Everything runs without *explicit* error, but the results from the call are wrong as compared to a basic `MultiLabelBinarizer`'s behavior:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

class ComposableMultiLabelBinarizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=False)
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.parent_feature = X.columns[0]
        self.mlb.fit(X)
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return self.mlb.transform(X)
    def get_feature_names(self):
        return [f'{self.parent_feature}_{c}' for c in self.mlb.classes_]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x0': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b'], ['d']]})
transformer = ColumnTransformer([('x0', ComposableMultiLabelBinarizer(), ['x0'])])
transformer.fit_transform(df[['x0']])
# array([[1, 1]])

MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(df['x0'])
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

It is unclear to me why the single-transformer `transformer` doesn't appropriately handle this case, especially since I'm not passing any custom classes via `MultiLabelBinarizer`'s `classes` option.

Comment: Voted to close, but after extensive digging found what I wanted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564903/how-to-transform-multiple-features-in-a-pipeline-using-featureunion

Comment: I suppose it is still unclear as to why this behavior occurs, but generally my problem was solved by the linked answer.